# How to skip the first element of a <ul> using BeautifulSoup (python)?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a python code that retrieve some data from a web page (web scrape).

Some point of the code it returns the follow list:

```
<ul class="nav nav--stacked" id="designer-list">
    <li>
        <h2>
            <a class="text-uppercase bold router-link-active" href="/en-ca/cars_all">
                All Cars
            </a>
        </h2>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/en-ca/cars/c1">
            <span>
                The car c1
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/en-ca/cars/c2">
            <span>
                The car c2
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am using `BeautifulSoup` and I just want to retrieve the references (`href`) for each car and its names.
In this example I want to retrieve (/en-ca/cars/c1)=>(The car c1) AND (/en-ca/cars/c2)=>(The car c2). I want to skip the first element (All cars).

I could use `.find_all('li')` and skip the first element inside the loop.
I was wondering if is there a way to reject the element trough  BeautifulSoup methods

Comment: In general, you can get an array and make it count from 1 by putting it as [1:].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this, though its not trough BeautifulSoup methods

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

content = soup.find_all('li')[1:]
```

Comment: No need of `list()` here. `find_all` returns a list. So, directly use slicing.